# How to fastly access the variable in a function?

Tags: matlab, performance

I have a function `cal_power` that called many times (3000times) in my main project. It uses the loop-up table way to perform computing the power of a scale number (follows some rule to make the table). The `TABLE` is a vector `1x510`.

In my current solution, for each time the function `cal_power` is called, the `TABLE` is initialization again, thus it takes some waste time. We know that the value in `TABLE` is fixed, do we have anyway in MATLAB to initialize the value of `TABLE` just one time, and it can access anywhere? I tried to use a global variable but it spends more time than my current solution. Thanks

```
function p = cal_power( ii )
% Input: ii: Integer in {0,255} (forced to be, if not)
% Output: 
%     p = TABLE( mod( ii, 255) + 1 );
% TABLE : look-up table

TABLE =  [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 29, 58, 116, 232, 205, 135, 19, 38, 76,...
   152, 45, 90, 180, 117, 234, 201, 143, 3, 6, 12, 24, 48, 96, 192, 157,...
   39, 78, 156, 37, 74, 148, 53, 106, 212, 181, 119, 238, 193, 159, 35,...
   70, 140, 5, 10, 20, 40, 80, 160, 93, 186, 105, 210, 185, 111, 222,...
   161, 95, 190, 97, 194, 153, 47, 94, 188, 101, 202, 137, 15, 30, 60,...
   120, 240, 253, 231, 211, 187, 107, 214, 177, 127, 254, 225, 223, 163,...
   91, 182, 113, 226, 217, 175, 67, 134, 17, 34, 68, 136, 13, 26, 52,...
   104, 208, 189, 103, 206, 129, 31, 62, 124, 248, 237, 199, 147, 59,...
   118, 236, 197, 151, 51, 102, 204, 133, 23, 46, 92, 184, 109, 218,...
   169, 79, 158, 33, 66, 132, 21, 42, 84, 168, 77, 154, 41, 82, 164, 85,...
   170, 73, 146, 57, 114, 228, 213, 183, 115, 230, 209, 191, 99, 198,...
   145, 63, 126, 252, 229, 215, 179, 123, 246, 241, 255, 227, 219, 171,...
   75, 150, 49, 98, 196, 149, 55, 110, 220, 165, 87, 174, 65, 130, 25,...
   50, 100, 200, 141, 7, 14, 28, 56, 112, 224, 221, 167, 83, 166, 81,...
   162, 89, 178, 121, 242, 249, 239, 195, 155, 43, 86, 172, 69, 138, 9,...
   18, 36, 72, 144, 61, 122, 244, 245, 247, 243, 251, 235, 203, 139, 11,...
   22, 44, 88, 176, 125, 250, 233, 207, 131, 27, 54, 108, 216, 173, 71,...
   142, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 29, 58, 116, 232, 205, 135, 19, 38,...
   76, 152, 45, 90, 180, 117, 234, 201, 143, 3, 6, 12, 24, 48, 96, 192,...
   157, 39, 78, 156, 37, 74, 148, 53, 106, 212, 181, 119, 238, 193, 159,...
   35, 70, 140, 5, 10, 20, 40, 80, 160, 93, 186, 105, 210, 185, 111,...
   222, 161, 95, 190, 97, 194, 153, 47, 94, 188, 101, 202, 137, 15, 30,...
   60, 120, 240, 253, 231, 211, 187, 107, 214, 177, 127, 254, 225, 223,...
   163, 91, 182, 113, 226, 217, 175, 67, 134, 17, 34, 68, 136, 13, 26,...
   52, 104, 208, 189, 103, 206, 129, 31, 62, 124, 248, 237, 199, 147,...
   59, 118, 236, 197, 151, 51, 102, 204, 133, 23, 46, 92, 184, 109, 218,...
   169, 79, 158, 33, 66, 132, 21, 42, 84, 168, 77, 154, 41, 82, 164, 85,...
   170, 73, 146, 57, 114, 228, 213, 183, 115, 230, 209, 191, 99, 198,...
   145, 63, 126, 252, 229, 215, 179, 123, 246, 241, 255, 227, 219, 171,...
   75, 150, 49, 98, 196, 149, 55, 110, 220, 165, 87, 174, 65, 130, 25,...
   50, 100, 200, 141, 7, 14, 28, 56, 112, 224, 221, 167, 83, 166, 81,...
   162, 89, 178, 121, 242, 249, 239, 195, 155, 43, 86, 172, 69, 138, 9,...
   18, 36, 72, 144, 61, 122, 244, 245, 247, 243, 251, 235, 203, 139, 11,...
   22, 44, 88, 176, 125, 250, 233, 207, 131, 27, 54, 108, 216, 173, 71,...
   142];

p = TABLE( mod( ii, 255) + 1 );
```

Comment: leave it in the workspace

Comment: Hi, you mean save the `TABLE` as TABLE.mat and call `load TABLE.mat` in the `cal_power` function. Is it right?

Comment: No I mean TABLE is just an array so you can just index it. No function is needed. Or pass to the function as an argument. Or use `evalin`

Comment: Could you give me the example in an answer. I will measure the time-consuming.

Comment: You don't need a function just use `p = TABLE( mod( ii, 255) + 1 );`

Comment: But where is TABLE define? I call it in some functions in the project.

Comment: You can define it as a persistent (static) variable in the scripts where ever the cal_power function is called. The variable then will be assigned once and won't expire between function calls and hence might reduce time footprint. Refer : https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101556-is-it-possible-to-define-a-variable-as-static-within-a-matlab-matlab-file

Comment: @SaurabhSaini: Using persistent  takes long time than not use :D

Answer (score 1):

Just use [Matlab Persistent Variable](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/persistent.html):

```
function p = cal_power( ii )
% Input: ii: Integer in {0,255} (forced to be, if not)
% Output: 
%     p = TABLE( mod( ii, 255) + 1 );
% TABLE : look-up table
persistent TABLE;

if isempty(TABLE)
    TABLE =  [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 29, 58, 116, 232, 205, 135, 19, 38, 76,...
    152, 45, 90, 180, 117, 234, 201, 143, 3, 6, 12, 24, 48, 96, 192, 157,...
    39, 78, 156, 37, 74, 148, 53, 106, 212, 181, 119, 238, 193, 159, 35,...
    70, 140, 5, 10, 20, 40, 80, 160, 93, 186, 105, 210, 185, 111, 222,...
end
```

UPDATE:

The following Code featuring the persistent variable took 0.034 seconds on my machine compared to 0.039 seconds without persistent:

```
tic
for i=1:3000
    ii = round(rand*254)+1;
    p=cal_power(ii);
end
toc
```

So I don't see that it is slower at all. Especially not by a factor 5.

If you still need a different solution, initialize the TABLE in the beginning of your main-function and just pass it to cal_power as additional parameter.

```
function p = cal_power( ii , TABLE)
% don't initialize TABLE here anymore
...
end
```

This way you make sure that TABLE only gets initialized once. Passing the variable as a reference should not consume much computation time too.

Comment: As I mentioned, the persistent way is slower 5x than non-persistent way

Comment: Even if you check for isempty() ? Because from the comments above it looked to me, like when you were using global or persistent variables, you still were initializing it on every call of cal_power(). Of course a global variable is slower than a local one - but doing the initialization of TABLE each and every time should be much more time consuming.

Comment: Yes, I check isempty also. You can also check it in MATLAB

Comment: @user3051460 Please consider accepting my answer or add additional information to your question to enable me and others to give further advice. Thank you